# Getting events from multiple calendarId using kloudless

Tags: google-calendar-api, kloudless

I'm using kloudless to connect into google calendar with different calendar_ids.

Currently what I've did was
CURL calling `/v1/accounts/{account_id}/cal/calendars/{calendar_id}/events/`
multiple times (and works).

However I wanted to make it efficent by single CURL call if possible.

Is there any kloudless API which can fetch events from multiple calendar_ids at the same time ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I work at Kloudless)

Thanks for the suggestion. The Kloudless API doesn’t yet support batch requests, but I've tracked this possible improvement in our backlog and made a note to let you know once it's available.

At the moment, individual requests are required as they map 1-1 to upstream requests to the calendar service.